# How to get compaign data , google analytics android?

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am using google analytics to:

1.check which campaign are referring the user to google play.

2.associate user id with a campaign. so i could check How much active users a specific campaign lead to.

I've did the first part. but the second one i didn't know how to do it ?

in google [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns#general-campaigns) , they don't explain how to get the campaign data, they just say that i should get that from the intent. but which intent ?